# 'invalid-email-address' on Github

Tags: github

When I do a `Pull Request` on a project on `Github` it shows [image: invalid-email-address]

Here is what I did:

1. `git clone` the project from `Github`
2. create a new branch and made some changes
3. `git commit` the changes, but `git` warns that my name and email address were configured automatically, so I run

> git config --global --edit

to change the default name and email to the same one as on my Github account (well, I'm not sure if the name is the same, but the email is definitely the same)

4. then run and edit the right name and email by

> git commit --amend --reset-author

5. `git push origin mybranch`

Why it shows invalid email address on Github and how can I fix the email address?

Answer (score 4):

Ignore that git is configuring your email and because, is not happening because your are not signed in at the moment that you clone your repository. Or your global configuration is empty

So reconfigure your  email and name

```
git config --global user.name "Your Name"
git config --global user.email you@example.com
```

Then add a commit message and run

```
git commit --amend --reset-author
```

of course push again